# HDF4 file on Anaconda distribution of python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, hdf, pyhdf

I am trying to read an HDF4 file with my Anaconda python distributions on 64-bit Windows 7. I have tried to do a conda install of both the pyhdf and pyNio packages, but Anaconda seems to find neither. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this? I tried to add conda.binstar.org/mutirri to my .condarc file, but conda says it still can't find the packages....thanks!

Comment: That binstar channel only has packages for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated pyHDF source to create Anaconda distribution for Windows 7 that works with the latest HDF4:

http://hdfeos.org/software/pyhdf.php

You can find 32-bit version.

We also provide instruction for building one on Windows so you can try it for 64-bit version.

Comment: Are there any plans to provide a version for 64 bit anaconda?

Comment: We are sorry but we don't have resources to support 64 bit. Please consider funding [special project](https://www.hdfgroup.org/services) for pyhdf maintenance.